# How to float an image within a dynamic div to the bottom right hand corner of the div?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, image

I want this icon image to be positioned at the bottom right hand corner of this div, so that it looks like the message is coming from the icon's head. I've fooled around with a bunch of things but haven't figured out a concrete solution.

[image: This is what it looks like right now.]

The relevant bit of css code

```
img.to{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        float:right;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        content:url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-1/60/05-512.png");
    }

.messageContainer{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.message.to {
    border-radius: 3em 3em .5em 3em;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    float:right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 12em;

}
```

The relevant bit of html using angular

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages | async">
    <div class="messageContainer">
         <img class="icon" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.sentBy === 'bot',
                                    'to':   message.sentBy === 'user' }"/>
        <div class="message" [ngClass]="{ 'from': message.sentBy === 'bot',
                                    'to':   message.sentBy === 'user' }" [innerHTML]=message.content>
         </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Relevant HTML sans angular as suggested

```
<div class="messageContainer">
         <img class="icon to">
        <div class="message to" >example message where i want the icon to be in the bottom right hand corner of the div</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Using flexbox you can easily set the elements how you wish. See this guide for more info on flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Why do you need it to float? Does it have to push specific content that otherwise occupies that space, when the element is not there? Also, consider adding a [mcve] to your question. In current form, someone needs to also know angular to answer but you only need CSS expertise. Replace Angular markup with its output (normal HTML).

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for the suggestion! Just updated the question. It doesn't necessarily need to be floated, just needs to be positioned in the bottom right corner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to create a space in the right side of the parent and give the parent `position:relative`. Than use `position:absolute; bottom: 0;` and `right: 0` (or even a negative value to get the child out of the background area of the parent).

Here's a basic example:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 1rem 4rem 1rem .5rem;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0;
}
.icon {
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #999;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -3.5rem;
}


/* rest is just adding some style, you don't need it. couldn't help it :) */

body {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.icon {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  transition: box-shadow .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1), bottom .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.parent:hover .icon {
  bottom: .2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.1), 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.07), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  LoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Elit ut aliquam purus sit amet. Nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper. Vestibulum morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi. Ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget. Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed.
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  Nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus. Tellus in hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed.
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  Volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida. Pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas fringilla. At elementum eu facilisis sed odio. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in. Eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. Odio ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut sem. Dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla pellentesque dignissim. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Arcu bibendum at varius vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras. Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra.
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Always set the parent div to `relative` and the child div (in this case image containing div) as `absolute`:

```
.chat-layout {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block 
}

.corner-image{
  position : absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Hint: be aware about text containing div to have right padding or z-index...